# Webpack Не создает .css в /dist

Tags: webpack

Пытаюсь подключить плагин mini-css-extract-plugin, несколько раз сверялся с примерами других людей, но при запуске сборки, собранного .css нет в директории dist.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader'
            ]
        },
        // {
        //     test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        //     loader: 'sass-loader'
        // }
    ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        overlay: true
    },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack_template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webpack template",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Olegexe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Сборка-то вообще проходит? Что вебпак пишет?

Comment: Hash: f1bed36c1d34163e7c2e
Version: webpack 4.41.2
Time: 759ms
Built at: 2019-11-14 10:01:06 AM
 Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.js  993 bytes       0  [emitted]  app
Entrypoint app = app.js
[0] ./src/index.js 21 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./src/js/common.js 74 bytes {0} [built]

А файл стилей игнорирует
если что, он в src/css/style.css

Comment: Так, а вы этот файл стилей вообще подключили хоть к чему-нибудь? Есть причина, по которой он не должен игнорироваться?

Comment: Я может не до конца понял суть плагина, поправьте меня если это не так. Но вроде как он должен собирать все файлы .css проекта в один, а потом уже этот файл и подключают

Comment: Нет, все css-файлы никто нигде никогда не собирает (и js-файлов это тоже касается), всё собирается строго по прописанным зависимостям, так что хотя бы в entry пропишите что ли

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка в том, что в index.js не импортированы начальные стили, которые потом обрабатывает webpack.
Попробуйте в index.js добавить:

```
import './css/main.css'
import './scss/main.scss'
```